# Rsync errors on windows with DeltaCopy

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, rsync

Previously I got this working on my workstation, but since I formatted it, rsync stopped to work.

I already reinstalled `git` and `deltacopy` a couple of times.
Also had registered rsync as a service on windows.

Every time I ran the command, I got these errors.
If I type a wrong password, I get access denied, so the connection is ok.

```
C:\\> rsync -v -rlt -z --chmod=a=rw,Da+x --delete 
      "/cygdrive/C/P21 Sistemas/web/apache/local.sdt21/sdt21/" 
      "root@sdt21.com.br:/home/sdt21/homologacao/www/sdt21/"

root@sdt21.com.br's password: *********

dup() in/out/err failed
rsync: read error: Connection reset by peer (104)
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at 
      /home/lapo/packaging/rsync-3.0.4-1/src/rsync-3.0.4/io.c(791)  [sender=3.0.4]**
```

Comment: What is your workstation? Is it the windows machine or the Ubuntu box?

Comment: @JensHöpken the windows one

Comment: Have you tried running with `-vvv` to get more diagnostics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `"`.

The quote is a known issue on Windows.
In order to override the problem install `cygwin` & `rsync`:

See: [Using rsync and cygwin to Sync Files from a Linux Server to a Windows Notebook PC](http://www.trueblade.com/knowledge/using-rsync-and-cygwin-to-sync-files-from-a-linux-server-to-a-windows-notebook-pc)

And then write your command in a shell script and execute it.